# Spark Java Can only define one get() function

Tags: java, spark-java

In my code I have two `get` functions, one for

```
get("/login",(request...))
```

and one for

```
get("/",(request....))
```

If I put the "/login" function before the "/" function only the "/login" page works and vice versa.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong, I had incorrect code syntax